# On Liggett's approximation of functions in $C(X)$.

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability

Liggett on his 2005 book Interacting Particle Systems on page 20
 defines the state space  a  state for a particle system $X = W^S$  where one should keep in mind the case where $S = \Bbb{Z}^d$ and $W = \{0,1\}$.

Then he gives a concrete way to construct approximation of functions in $C(X)$:

[image]

My question is about the last line. When Liggett writes $\zeta \in W^T$ shouldn't it be instead $W^S$ since in this case $f_T$ and $f$ will have the same domain, otherwise it makes no sense to say that $f_T$ approximates $f$.

Is this a typo or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I see it on page 22 in the 1985 edition. I do think the text is correct. If it is an error though, Liggett should be notified as I don't see it on the errata posted on his website.

The reason I think it's correct: For any $\xi,\zeta\in W^S$ that are identical on $T$, $f_T(\xi)=f_T(\zeta)$ since $f_T$ only sees a fixed $\eta$ outside of $T$ (I would have preferred it be called $f_{T,\eta}$).

So, yes, the domain of $f_T$ is $W^S$, but it is only supported on or can only resolve $W^T$ in a sense. So $\xi\in W^T$ is all we need to evaluate $f_T(\xi)$ (i.e. we just need to know $\xi$ restricted to $T$).

In some sense, it's cleaner they way he has done it, because it reinforces the fact that $f_T(\xi)=f_T(\zeta)$ when the configurations are identical on $T$.

**Other thoughts:** When he's states that $f_T(\zeta)=f(\eta^\zeta)$ for $\zeta\in W^T$, we could think of it as operating on the equivalence class $\zeta=\{\eta\in W^S \mid \eta(i)=\zeta(i), i=x,y\}$.

Alternatively we could realize that $f_T$ is defined outside of $T$ completely by $f$ and $\eta$, so it is only necessary to define $f_T$ on $W^T$, otherwise it's somewhat redundant.

Comment: I see your point jdods, but what is the meaning of approximating functions with different domains.... It seems that we must agree on the idea that if $B \subset A$, $f: A \to C$ and $g:B \to C$ then $f(x) = g(x) $ for $x \in A$ implies that $g$ is a good approximation of $f$ in some sense. This is the point of the question. To my mind the domain of $f_T$ or as will nicely pointed out $f_{T, \eta}$ should be $W^S$ and not $W^T$. Don't you think?

Comment: Is it specifically stated that $W^T$ is the *domain*? It's just defined on $W^T$ and has an obvious extension to all of $W^S$. The concept of *natural domain* may be applicable here. Consider a function that only uses the 1st digit of a decimal expansion. It only requires definition on a subset but has a natural extension to any number. Maybe this is poor style, but is it actually incorrect mathematically?

Comment: I don't think it is incorrect, I was just having trouble understanding it. Therefore the question.

Comment: It's a good question. I think it should be asked in the general context regarding defining functions. I'll post the general question later, if you don't.

Comment: I asked the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768728/is-this-an-incorrect-way-to-define-a-function and so far it has gotten negative feedback, but the comments are leading me to believe that you are correct in this instance and this should be reported as a typo to Liggett.